# How can I free up other volume space on Mac partitions

Tags: macos

It's fresh OS X, as you can see in there other volume take 297.74 GB.
How can I free it? Please advise.

[image: can see here]

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing free space, it is space as the names says, used by other volumes in the APFS container.

Select Disk Utility's menu item **View > Show All Devices** and the left sidebar will show the APFS container disk. Select the container and the bar graph will show all the volumes in the container.

A big-chunk of the used space is probably "OSX - Data" – this volume and "OSX" form a pair which Catalina presents as the single "OSX" volume; the "OSX" volume contains the write-protected system files while the "OSX - Data" volume contains the writeable part of the filesystem. How this works is covered in one of Apple's WWDC presentations.

HTH